# How to pass my auth_token and refresh tokens to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api-ruby-client

I'm using the `google-api-ruby-client` gem in rails.

In the examples I found an example to load GooglePlus data:

```
client = Google::Apis::PlusV1::PlusService.new
client.key = ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID']
client.authorization = authorization
```

**I have already obtained both `refresh_token` and the `auth_token` with another method** (using devise oauth).

How can I generate the `authorization` object, starting from the tokens I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the authorization object by instantiate a new UserRefreshCredentials like this:

```
 authorization = Google::Auth::UserRefreshCredentials.new(
      client_id: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
      client_secret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
      scope: GOOGLE_SCOPE,
      access_token: YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN,
      refresh_token: YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN,
      expires_at: YOUR_EXPIRE_AT_TIMESTAMP,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code')
```